# Why is there a unique blessing for Yom Kippur candle lighting?

Tags: yom-kippur, candle-lighting

Yom Kippur candle lighting has unique blessing

> להדליק נר של יום הכפורים

Technically, we could argue that since Yom Tov is called "Shabbat" (see Leviticus 23 as an example), we should have just one blessing להדליק נר של  שבת . I'm assuming that they instituted a separate blessing for Yom Tov, because one may light a fire from another fire on Yom Tov - something that you cannot do on Shabbat.

But Yom Kippur is much like Shabbat anyway, as one cannot do work or light a fire, just as on Shabbat. Why not use the Shabbat blessing for Yom Kippur?

Comment: Note not every place has the custom to light candles for Yom Kippur (Pesachim 4:4). it appears not to be a part of the enactment regarding other holidays.

Comment: This is the only case I can think of where Rosh Hashana has the same nusach as every other Yom Tov but Yom Kippur has its own.

Comment: @Heshy You may want to browse beureihatefilah.com. If I recall correctly, they say that the Shemoneh Eserh for Rosh Hashanna and Yom Kippur originally used *Vehasieneu* - the same as all other yom Tovim, prior to having a change which was done numerous years later.

Comment: @Heshy I believe that on Rosh Hashana Chabad recite the blessing with the text להדליק נר של יום הזכרון

Answer (score -2):

I think it's because **yom kipur** is called **SHABAT SHABTON**,
so there is a spechial blessing.

> Vayikra *perek* 16 *pasuk* 31 `שַׁבַּת שַׁבָּתוֹן הִיא לָכֶם, וְעִנִּיתֶם אֶת-נַפְשֹׁתֵיכֶם--חֻקַּת, עוֹלָם.`

So this is more then a regular Shabbat.

[EDIT]

because **yom kipur** isn't like a regular  **SHABAT** according to the *pasuk*,
so threre is a unique blessing.

[EDIT]
I only see no all the comments but I will explain my answer, as OP understand why for Yom Tov there is another blessing the same applies here for Yom Kippur because it's not the same as regular  **SHABAT**
as you see in the pasuk.

Hopefully its better now

Comment: Hi Moshe, welcome to MY. Your answer could be greatly improved if you added some sources (where it's called Shabbos Shabboson) and expanded on how that applies here. Hope to see you around!

Comment: I'm downvoting your answer, for now, as it shows no correlation between the verse that you cited and the blessing for cancle lighting. As you know, the mitzvah of candle lighting in the home is not mentioned anywhere in the Torah. Neither are the blessings. If you can show this correlation with a source, I'll be please to change the vote.

Comment: He said "I think." . Is it proper to downvote when one gives one's own opinion?(or did "I think" mean he thinks so from a forgotten source?)

Comment: @davidk either way it's just his word against anyone else's for now. See my opinion about downvotes without sources at https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1446/759

Comment: @DavidKenner Other than the unsourced aspect, I down-voted this, because the opinion itself doesn't appear to correlate the verse to candle lighting blessings.

Comment: "regular" Shabbos is also called "Shabbat shabbaton."