# Why do we say "shel Yom HaKippurim" for Yom Kippur candlelighting but "shel Yom Tov" for all other Yom Tovim?

Tags: blessing, yom-kippur, candle-lighting

I recognize that Yom Kippur is special, VERY special. But Rosh Hashanah, Sukkot, Pesach and Shavuot aren't exactly chopped liver, as the saying goes. And it is no more difficult to say "shel Rosh Hashanah" or "shel Sukkot" than it is to say "shel Yom Tov". So why do we say "shel Yom HaKippurim" for Yom Kippur candlelighting but "shel Yom Tov" for all other Yom Tovim? Many thanks for any insight and thoughts. Chag Sukkot Sameach!

Comment: Not a duplicate of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/81426/170

Comment: As noted in the link above, the impetus to light on those nights are different things.